# Angularjs directive, different ways of doing template to avoid {{}} resolution problems

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

We have an angular app and recently we added a mechanism to optionally allow users to upload a custom font and then render the app in that custom font.  The guy who implemented it threw in a directive that declares a  block and defines the font override based on the user's customizations on the page.

The thing that tweaked the QA team is that before that customization data comes back, they're seeing a 404 request for /{{fontPath}}/{{customFont}} until all of the digest cycles go through.

I've been trying to make the 404 go away and have run into some things that puzzle me.

First, here's what things look like

```
<div font-override ng-if="customFont"></div>
```

and the directive templateUrl looks like

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'FontOverride';
        src: url("{{fontPath}}{{customFont}}") format('woff');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'FontOverride';
        src: url("{{fontPath}}{{customFont_bold}}") format('woff');
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'FontOverride';
        src: url("{{fontPath}}{{customFont_italic}}") format('woff');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'FontOverride';
        src: url("{{fontPath}}{{customFont_boldItalic}}") format('woff');
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .ourApp *:not(.fa) {
        font-family: 'FontOverride' !important;
    }
</style>
```

And when the templateUrl contents are swapped in, there's an immediate 404 request for "/{{fontPath}}{{customFont}}"

I've been playing with a bunch of things trying to get that to go away.  I put ng-cloak both on the div and inside the templateUrl contents.  It didn't work.

I tried defining the ng-cloak style and setting it as a css class on the style node (found this in another stack oflow article) but it didn't work.

On a wild hare, I tried taking the contents of the templateUrl file and embedding it in the directive code with a template literal

```
template: ``
```

That didn't work at first but started to after I removed the quotes around url("{{fontPath}}{{customFont}}").

Not clear why or how or at what point the templating is getting resolved or why that worked better (wrt the 404) than templateUrl.  I mean, from what I found about ECMA6, the actual template bits are ${}, not {{}}.

Then I tried it in IE11 (since we're still nominally supporting that) and of course template literals didn't work there.  So I tried building the multi-line thing as an old string

```
"<style>\r\n" +
"    @font-face { font-family: 'FontOverride'; src: url('{{fontPath}}{{customFont}}') format('woff'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; } \r\n\r\n" +
...
"    .ourApp *: not(.fa) {\r\n         font-family: 'FontOverride' !important;\r\n }\r\n</style>\r\n"
```

The last line of the style seemed to be more newline/whitespace sensitive, so I was trying to preserve it.

This worked in no browser I tried.  Chrome, IE, Edge all rendered it identically when I inspected the elements but the font was neither fetched nor applied at any stage.  Firefox appeared to be stripping the newlines from the literal in the first place.

So...
1) Why did template: `` work without producing the 404 request in the first place?

2) I was trying to use ECMA6 template literals just to get multi-line constants; I didn't expect the template constructs to be working directly, as ECMA6 uses ${} instead of {{}}, but maybe EMCA6 template literals also get angular syntax?  Or maybe angular is jacking into jquery syntax and making kind of a synonym?

3) Why do clunky old string literal with \r\n in them render identically in most browsers but not produce the functional impact?  Kinda loops back to the theory that ECMA6 template literals are getting evaluated by angular in a different way.

Insights appreciated.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `<style>` tag will be parsed (and the `src`'s will be loaded) by the browser way before Angular gets instantiated in the page. Which means before the `ng-if` is applied.

You need to store that markup without allowing the browser to parse it as a `<style>` tag.

A typical solution for such cases is to wrap it in a

```
<script type="text/template">
  <style>...</style>
</script>
```

It's a common pattern for dynamic templates.  When your component loaded, select the script by id, grab its `.html()`, `$compile` and append.

For some reason, I can't get it to work on [SO], but you can see it working in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/khjr70ep/

I didn't have your files, so I used some random google font, but you can see it doesn't load before parsing.

And it applies the font.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The <style> tag is currently in the angular template, not in the page itself, so some part of angular had to be going before it got there.  I'm just not clear why having a directive yank it in from a template (vs an ECMA6 template literal)  opens a gap where the uninterpreted expression gets fetched.  And then gets fetched again after the expressions are resolved.  And I'm not clear why the template literal is working but a hand-crafted, multi-line string is not.  Those are the crux of the question.

Comment: The fact that the request leaves before `ng-if` is applied tells us the browser sees that markup before angular compiles it. Try my suggestion. It should work. I'll try to add a generic example. If you have a [mcve] I could use it, especially if it features the problem.

Comment: @user, added a fiddle. I have no idea why [so] blocks it, when trying the same in a snippet here, but you can see it's functioning correctly in the fiddle.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar.  I made the template empty, set a watch in the directive link to fill the template in and $compile when it was set.  Still not sure why template literals worked without $compile or the other questions, but still good to have it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be to declare an empty style tag with id attribute, inside your template, for instance:

```
<style id="app-custom-font-css"></style>
```

Then when the fonts have been already uploaded to its final location and you got the data, use it to build the CSS content:

```
// Update <style> tag with specific ID
const styleTag = document.getElementById('app-custom-font-css');
styleTag.innerHTML = myCustomCssContentString;
```

The above can be done from the directive or when your app has loaded. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll probably end up going down a route like this, but I'm trying to understand a few things about angular's digestive tract first - like why template literals work without producing a 404 request while pulling it in via  templateUrl opens a gap producing a 404.  And why a multi-line constant (not a template literal) produces no functional result even though it renders identically (in most browsers)